# 'Memory allocatable utilization' for kubernetes.io/node > 100%

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to configure monitoring on a variety of Kubernetes (GKE) nodes, specifically to identify [near] out-of-memory conditions. The documentation for `node/memory/allocatable_utilization` states:

> This value cannot exceed 1 as usage cannot exceed allocatable memory bytes.

However, it reports a `non-evictable` value > 1 (1.015), which contradicts that constraint. Also, it's not clear to me how this corresponds with the actual condition on the node, as shown by `free -m`:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15038       10041         184          67        4812        4606
Swap:             0           0           0
```

This node is designed to run memory-intensive workloads (Java) and as such this is in line with what I'd expect per our heap size planning.

Why would Stackdriver report this value with those conditions on the node?

Comment: Answering my own question in a way - What Stackdriver reports as "utilization" in the context of the Kubernetes Node and the memory utilization you get from the monitoring agent (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) are totally different. The latter is much more in line with what you get from `free`, and is in my experience consistently less than what the GKE metric displays.